# problems sourcing in an .R file into python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

In rpy 1.x, to source in a .R file, all one had to do was this:

> ```
> import rpy 
> rpy.r.source("filename.R")
> ```

In rpy2, what needs to happen in order to source in a .R file from Python?

I have tried several avenues, such as this:

> ```
> import rpy2.robjects as ro
> ro.source("filename.R")
> ```

Returns an error like this (sorry if this doesn't format correctly):

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 166, in __call__
return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 99, in __call__
res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
RRuntimeError: Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
cannot open the connection
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: have you tried `pip install rpy --upgrade`? It seems others had this Trace in the past, and there was a fix, though that happened some time ago...

Comment: No I haven't.  I am using Python 2.7.3, and I am using this install of rpy2, which appears to be the most current for Python verison I am using?: rpy2-2.4.3.win32-py2.7, along with R version 2.15.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to [run arbitrary R code](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/robjects_rinstance.html#evaluating-a-string-as-r-code) with `rpy2.robjects.r()` (or `.R()`, don't think there's a difference):

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

ro.r("""source('filename.R')""")
```

I'd test `filename.R` first in RStudio (or your preferred alternative) first, just to make sure it's a valid file and can be sourced without issues.

Comment: interesting. Thanks. What is the purpose of having to include those three quotations before and after?  Is it converting to a string or something?  It just seems so radically different than how it was done before.  Not sure why the developer did it that way.  Simple is better than complex.

Comment: @myClone the purpose of the triple quotes is two-fold: first, they allow you to use single and double quotes within them without having to escape anything. Second, they allow you to have multi-line strings, so instead of just executing one command at a time, you can put as many as you want together, or simply separate one complex command onto multiple lines.

Comment: so what if I have a file location defined further up in the python script such as codeLoc = "../rcode", and I need to reference that codeLoc in the ro.r("""source('filename.R')""")?  How would I correctly reference that?

Comment: @myClone you can use string formatting for that. See the bottom example in the link in my answer, and read through the rest of the docs. `ro.r("""source(%s)""" % codeLoc)` should work.

Comment: Awesome--thanks for the resources. Still trying to get my head around rpy2!

Comment: Please see my edited question--I provided some additional context as to what I am looking for and what I think the problem might be.

Comment: @myClone **please** do not "[move the goalposts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252113/1426065)" by asking one question, accepting an answer, then changing your question to ask something else entirely and remove the accept. If you have a new question, [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it. You can always reference this one for context.

Comment: I removed the edit to my question, and I will ask a separate question. Sorry for violating "code".

Comment: @myClone no problem. If you read through the meta post I linked to, some people have used a single question to ask numerous things, which leads to confusion later on when new visitors read the current version of the question (and don't know about or don't read the edit history), then find answers that don't seem to be related at all. While your edit was somewhat related to the old question, I just wanted to make sure this didn't turn into one of those cases. Thanks for being a good sport!