# assigning then attaching a filepath name in python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

This is addendum to a question I asked yesterday: [Problems Sourcing in an R file into python using rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438097/problems-sourcing-in-an-r-file-into-python-using-rpy2)

The issue in my case is two fold.  @MattDMo's solution (Thanks Matt) to call in the .R script is correct. However, my error I think, is do to how the file path name is being referenced in the python script and then used to source in the .R file.

In my python script I have this,

```
codeLoc = "../rcode"
```

followed by this,

`rpy.r.assign("codeLoc", codeLoc)`

This assign function attaches the code location file path to a variable ("codeLoc") within the R script I am trying to source in.

Originally, the python script used this:

`rpy.r.source(codeLoc + "/filename.R")`

Really simple!
But now rpy2 has made things so that I have to use strings and such.  So, knowing that

`ro.r("""source('filename.R')""")`

sources in a .R script, how would I go about attaching a filepath name to the script so that I don't have to call it every time (as I need to use the same file path a few different times, and the path may change in the future).  Essentially, I need a correct rpy2 version of this psuedo code:

`ro.r("""source(codeLoc + ('/filename.R')""")`

my hunch is that I might need to change how codeLoc itself is assigned using rpy2? Maybe R and Python are not communicating with each other properly due to the improper use of the assign method?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new way actually makes things easier for you. Rather than having to make the call to r.assign, you can just specify the string (dynamically if you want) and call it. For example,

```
codeLoc = "../rcode"
r_call = "source('" + codeLoc + "/filename.R')"
ro.r(r_call)
```

**EDIT**
If you have a series of files that you want to open, you can call them dynamically in a for-loop. There are two cases I will address. First, the names are indexed (eg. filename1, filename2, etc.) and second, they are not indexed.

1) If the file names are indexed with ind_max being the maximum file number, you can `source` them as follows:

```
for num in range(ind_max):
    ro.r("source('" + codeLoc + "/filename" + str(num) + ".R')")
```

2) If the file names are not indexed, you can do the same thing by defining a list of the names you want to `source`:

```
names = ['spam', 'eggs']
for name in names:
    ro.r("source('" + codeLoc + "/filename" + name + ".R')")
```

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks.  So if I need to source in a few more files, would I do something like this?:

`r_call_1 = "source('" + codeLoc + "/filename1.R)
r_call_2 = "source('" + codeLoc + "/filename2.R)`

and then I could simply "attach" the files by calling each separately, or is there a cleaner way of calling multiple files?

Comment: Glad to help! I edited the answer to include instructions on how to do this for multiple files.